# Can I aggregate signals in an alias over multiple module instances?

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a top testbench in VHDL and at some point in the design, I have multiple module generation:

```
MOD_GEN: for i in 0 to 3 generate
  mod_i: example_module
  (...)
end generate;
```

For some testing purposes, I need an internal signal from *example_module* instances to be brought to the top testbench. However, I don't want to use:

```
alias tested_sig_0 is << signal (...).MOD_GEN(0).mod_i.tested_sig  : std_logic_vector >>;                 
alias tested_sig_1 is << signal (...).MOD_GEN(1).mod_i.tested_sig  : std_logic_vector >>; 
alias tested_sig_2 is << signal (...).MOD_GEN(2).mod_i.tested_sig  : std_logic_vector >>; 
alias tested_sig_3 is << signal (...).MOD_GEN(3).mod_i.tested_sig  : std_logic_vector >>;
```

Is there any way to aggregate these signals in a nice way?

Comment: There's an elaboration order requirement for external names (IEEE Std 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy, paragraph 15, the first case) requiring external path names not be used in alias declarations in a higher block level in a a design hierarchy. This means the aliases can't be declared in the top level testbench unless in a declarative region elaborated after MOD_GEN, either in a process statement or block statement. Concurrent statements are elaborated in the order they occur (14.5 Elaboration of a statement part). Provide a [mcve], show the declaration for `tested_sig`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot aggregate into an alias, because then it wouldnt be an alias. But you could aggregate them into a signal:

```
signal agg : std_logic_vector(tested_sig_0'length+tested_sig_1'length+tested_sig_2'length+tested_sig_3'length-1 downto 0);
...


agg <= tested_sig_0 & tested_sig_1 & tested_sig_2 & tested_sig_3;
```

Comment: The expression `tested_sig_0 & tested_sig_1 & tested_sig_2 & tested_sig_3` uses concatenation and isn't an aggregate. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.5 Adding operators, 9.3.3 Aggregates. 6.6 Alias declarations "An alias declaration declares an alternate name for an existing named entity."  An aggregate isn't a named entity.